# Is this "shared memory" IPC-object deleted?

Tags: linux, ipc, shared-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [deleting shared memory with ipcrm in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398886/deleting-shared-memory-with-ipcrm-in-linux)

I am running Fedora 15 64 bit. I have some shared memory that wasn't cleaned up by a process. You can see the shared memory when you call `ipcs -m`:

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x51012a29 294919     trevor     666        194400     2
```

When I call `ipcrm -m 294919` and then check to see if the shared memory is deleted you see:

```
------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      bytes      nattch     status      
0x00000000 294919     trevor     666        194400     2          dest
```

**IMO the shared memory is still there... because it shows up when i call `ipcs -m`. Is this shared memory actually deleted?**

Comment: (if I am missing some nuance please explain. like for example. maybe 'it is deleted but due to linux convention the shared memory you deleted still shows up because... $INSERT_EXPLANATION'. or maybe 'it is deleted ... the 'dest' means the shared memory is destroyed... it won't ever get deleted from ipcs -m unless you do so and so.').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a little bit of googling. Here's what I found;

dest apparently means marked to be destroyed. I am guessing it will not be destroyed unless it is being referenced or a transitory state.

http://www.puschitz.com/TuningLinuxForOracle.shtml

Comment: ya I just found out that "dest" means marked for destruction. To actually make the shared memory segment go away you need to kill the process using the shared memory segment.

Comment: soln: when you call `ipcs -mp` you get a list of the PIDs associated with the shared memory segment. Then you can kill based on the PID or lookup the name of the PID by doing `ps -ef | grep PID`. I checked to see who is using the shared memory and then killed it.